# Image can not be displayed on page

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have an img tag

```
 <img data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl() }" />
```

I binded it to `imageUrl()` function in knockoutjs.

```
self.imageUrl = ko.computed(function () {
                return "C:/Users/FC/Desktop/54f46f4613ba6106000d98f7.jpg";
 });
```

And I have an image that has JPEG format in my desktop.

Url is correct but I can not show this image on page. It can not be displayed.

What's problem?

Comment: To access from your local file system in this, you probably need to use `file://` protocol. This will not be available from a web application. A better solution is to put the image resource in a directory served by your webapp, and link to it there.

Comment: look and see if the browser reports a 404 error. Sometimes it might happen because of file permissions that keep the browser from referencing the file. I only have experience on mac, but look inside the inspector and it will tell you if the file permissions are wrong or if the file couldn't be found. Is/was the file inside xampp?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript cannot access your filesystem. Put the image where the webserver can see your assets and reference it by URL.

Comment: this would still be viewable in the browser, the protocol is missing

Comment: @Sphaso self.imageUrl = ko.computed(function () {
                return "file:\\c:\\users\fc\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\INDIVIDUAL\INDIVIDUAL\Images\UploadedImages\1_54f46f4613ba6106000d98f7.jpeg";
            }); I tried this but it didn't work

Comment: That's not what I was suggesting, but it's weird it doesn't work. Do you have any error in the console?. Ideally you shuold have a webServer (even locally) that serves your assets (js, css, html...). You'd have then a folder under the website root where you store images. This way you can access the images by, e.g. "/Content/blabla.jpg" (example of a relative URL).

Comment: @Sphaso Thanks a lot. You are right but I have to save images to this folder. I checked firebug but there is no error message

Comment: @LazyLooser Sorry, I need to check my eyesight. Look at the protocol, it should be file:// NOT file:\\

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the file protocol:

return "file://C:/Users/FC/Desktop/54f46f4613ba6106000d98f7.jpg"

still, you shouldn't be serving up resources from the local filesystem. consider using a webservice.

Comment: I put it to desktop for trying. In fact this image was in a folder that existed in my project directory. It didn't work